# How to insert NA values in a ts object to fill the gap with another time series?

Tags: r, time-series

(I'm new to R) I have two time series with different lengths, one starting from jan 2011 (ts1) and the other from jan 2016 (ts2).
How to fill the time interval "ts1 - ts2" (from jan 2011 to dec 2015) in ts2 with NA values to "align" it with ts1?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow! In the future please include an example of your data so that we can test the code before providing an answer. In this case, any time series object with different start dates would suffice. I have had to find my own data to answer your question.

First I load stock price data into R with the `quantmod` package. This returns objects that are of the class `xts`, which is convenient in this case. I've loaded `AAPL`, which starts from 2011 and `GOOG`, which starts from 2016. Now to achieve what you want, the easiest way is to create a new `xts` object from 2011 to 2016 and fill it with NAs. Then simply combine the shorter time series object with this new time series object that has NAs, in this case `GOOG`.

```r
library(quantmod)

getSymbols('AAPL', from = "2011-01-01", to = "2019-09-30")
getSymbols("GOOG", from = '2016-01-01', to = "2019-09-30")

new_rows <- nrow(AAPL) - nrow(GOOG)
temp <- matrix(NA, nrow = new_rows, ncol = ncol(GOOG))
temp <- xts(temp, order.by = index(AAPL[1:new_rows,,drop=F]))
column_names <- colnames(GOOG)
GOOG <- rbind(temp, GOOG)
colnames(GOOG) <- column_names
nrow(AAPL)==nrow(GOOG)
[1] TRUE
```

Now `GOOG` has the same start date as `AAPL` and it has NAs from 2011 to 2015 December.

Answer (score 1):

Say you have two time-series data.tables of different lengths:

```
dt1 = data.table(
  Date = seq(as.Date('2000-01-01'), as.Date('2000-01-10'), by = 1),
  Return1 = rnorm(10)
)

dt2 = data.table(
  Date = seq(as.Date('2000-01-05'), as.Date('2000-01-10'), by = 1),
  Return2 = rnorm(6)
)
```

You can perform merge() onto the two data.tables and supply the variable you want to merge them by. In this case, "Date". Furthermore, we pass the All = T argument in order to keep rows which are not in the union of Date entries across dt1 and dt2.

```
dtmain = merge(dt1, dt2, on = 'Date', all = T)

> dtmain
          Date    Return1     Return2
 1: 2000-01-01 -2.9934945          NA
 2: 2000-01-02 -0.6712139          NA
 3: 2000-01-03  0.2146184          NA
 4: 2000-01-04  1.2342134          NA
 5: 2000-01-05  0.3276646 -2.35205416
 6: 2000-01-06  1.1823349  0.39382064
 7: 2000-01-07 -0.8771251  0.72213968
 8: 2000-01-08 -0.8145120 -0.15433887
 9: 2000-01-09  1.0455526  0.05794934
10: 2000-01-10 -1.2378961 -0.49929648
```

Consider now if you have three or more time-series data.table objects:

```
dt3 = data.table(
  Date = seq(as.Date('2000-01-02'), as.Date('2000-01-8'), by = 1),
  Return3 = rnorm(7)
)
```

If you want to merge them all, you can use the following solution using Reduce():

```
dtlist = list(dt1, dt2, dt3) # Put your TS objects in a list
by = 'Date' # Declare the variable you want to merge the tables on

dtmain = Reduce(function(...) merge(..., all = TRUE, by = by), dtlist)

> dtmain
          Date     Return1    Return2    Return3
 1: 2000-01-01  0.45667875         NA         NA
 2: 2000-01-02 -0.84284705         NA  0.7747270
 3: 2000-01-03  0.58849764         NA -0.4224948
 4: 2000-01-04 -0.76110475         NA -0.7372464
 5: 2000-01-05  0.72950287 -0.6800249 -0.6412878
 6: 2000-01-06  1.65512675 -0.9477490  0.4073604
 7: 2000-01-07 -0.56407002  0.9283520  0.3264292
 8: 2000-01-08  0.05535025  1.7146754  0.7125701
 9: 2000-01-09  0.06031502  1.2413374         NA
10: 2000-01-10 -0.23840704  0.3846532         NA
```